# Regex that does not contain a substring after some point

Tags: python, regex

I want a regex that doesn't match a string if contains the word `page`, and match if it's not contain.

`^https?.+/(event|news)/.+(?!page).+$` this is the regex I'm currently using, so I want it to not match with, e.g. `https://www.foosite.com/news/foopath/page/10`, but it does. Where did I made a mistake?

The double `.+` expressions should imply that there should be some string around the `page` string, and `(?!page)` should imply there must not be a string like `page` between them. What's wrong with this expression? Thanks, and sorry for poor grammar.

Comment: will page word is always there in string ? if yes you can use lookahead [`Regex demo`](https://regex101.com/r/li1dxK/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need the regex match if the string doesn't contain `page`. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `.+(?!page).+` will match `foopath/page/10` because the first `.+` match can end at the `1` in `10`, and the second can match from there until `$`. Instead, just assert there is no combination of characters plus the word `page` after `(event|news)/`:

```
^https?.+/(event|news)/(?!.*page)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EO9Aqj/3)

If you want more than just a match/nomatch decision, you can capture the entire matching string with this regex:

```
^https?.+/(event|news)/(?!.*page).*$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EO9Aqj/4/)

Comment: This will allways only match links up to `https://www.foosite.com/news` even if they are longer and don't include `page`.

Comment: @CennoxX From the wording of the question, OP only wants a match/nomatch decision based on the presence of the word `page`. This regex will achieve that.

Comment: @CennoxX I've added a regex that will capture the entire string on a match if that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for

```
^https?.+/(event|news)/(?:(?!page).)+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/rn3HDZ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

*Matching* is usually way easier in regex than *excluding*.

I would rather *match* your excluded words and invert the logic on the if-clause.

`if(!re.match(...`